# How to distinct record from mongodb aggregate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents similar to this stored in `mongodb`.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f5f333733f1342b26c55d5d"),
    "timeCreated" : 1600073359524,
    "sender" : ObjectId("5ee096ee7febd3408828ce2c"),
    "onModel" : "Trend",
    "type" : ObjectId("5f3a49a12bf7e9118d0b9492"),
    "chat" : ObjectId("5f50cbc109f2a574a1efb219"),
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f5f333733f1342b26c55d5c"),
    "timeCreated" : 1600073359500,
    "sender" : ObjectId("5ee096ee7febd3408828ce2c"),
    "onModel" : "Trend",
    "type" : ObjectId("5f3a49a12bf7e9118d0b9492"),
    "chat" : ObjectId("5f50cbc109f2a574a1efb219"),
}
```

I want to distinct record on the basis of `type` `sender` `chat`.

Expected result would be like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f5f333733f1342b26c55d5d"),
    "timeCreated" : 1600073359524,
    "sender" : ObjectId("5ee096ee7febd3408828ce2c"),
    "onModel" : "Trend",
    "type" : ObjectId("5f3a49a12bf7e9118d0b9492"),
    "chat" : ObjectId("5f50cbc109f2a574a1efb219"),
}
```

Here is my query:

```
  await Share.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        sender: ObjectId(sender),
        onModel: onModel,
        chat: ObjectId(chat),
        ...timeCreatedCond,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "memories",
        foreignField: "_id",
        localField: "type",
        as: "memoryInfo",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "listings",
        foreignField: "_id",
        localField: "type",
        as: "listingInfo",
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "listingCategories",
        foreignField: "_id",
        localField: "listingInfo.listingCategory",
        as: "listingCategories",
      },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { sender: "$sender", type: "$type", chat: "$chat" },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: -1,
        sender: 1,
        type: 1,
        chat: 1,
        memoryInfo: 1,
        listingInfo: 1,
        listingCategories: 1,
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: { created: -1 },
    },
    {
      $skip: skip,
    },
    {
      $limit: limit,
    },
  ]);
```

Comment: Hello, What have you tried ? I think you're looking for : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: @AlexisG Yes I am trying with aggregation and group. I will update my query in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$group` stage is only passing `_id` to the next stage.
You need to pass the other fields, since there is no particular operation.
A [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) should do it

```
    {
      $group: {
        _id: { sender: "$sender", type: "$type", chat: "$chat" },
        sender: {"$first"},
        type: {"$first": "$type"},
        chat: {"$first": "$chat"},
        memoryInfo: {"$first": "$memoryInfo"},
        listingInfo: {"$first": "$listingInfo"},
        listingCategories: {"$first": "$listingCategories"},
      },
    },
```

Comment: It works but one thing is missing. You should add `sender: {"$first": "$sender"}`.